# Where is the path property on category set?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am working on a new Menu structure and needs to replicate the way path is added to Categories.
I have tried to search through the code to locate where path is added - but I can't seem to find it anyware.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is indexed to a `category` by the `CategoryIndexer` calling `TreeUpdater::batchUpdate` and [there's where the path is build](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b9710d639753cf42718987ab83467ac52a1170dd/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Indexing/TreeUpdater.php#L374).